# How to set drop down text and value by using other drop down in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

**Here is my code**

I have ddlvehicle like below

```
<option value="1">A</option>
<option value="2">B</option>        
<option value="3">C</option>                

ddl=Ctrl("ddlvehicle");
$("#ddltrVehicle").empty();
for(var i=2;i<=ddl.options.length;i++)
{
    $("#ddltrVehicle").append("<option value="+ddl.options[i-1].value+">"+ddl.options[i-1].value+"</option>");
}
```

I want to assign  the ddlvehicle to ddltrvehicle , my code only results like the below

I have ddltrVehicle like below

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>        
<option value="3">3</option>
```

please help to get the ddltrVehicle like ddlvehicle.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `text` like,

```
var ddl=$("#ddlvehicle")[0];
$("#ddltrVehicle").empty();
for(var i=2;i<=ddl.options.length;i++)
{
   $opt="<option value="+ddl.options[i-1].value+">"+ddl.options[i-1].text+"</option>";
                         // ---------------------------------------- ^ Use text here
   $("#ddltrVehicle").append($opt);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4nwZq/)

Comment: It worked.Previously I have tried the same  with ddl.options[i-1].text() and got disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

Let try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('#ddlvehicle').children().length; i++){
  $('#ddltrvehicle').append($('#ddlvehicle').children().eq(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I din't understand question well, but if you want to copy all options of `ddlvehicle` to `ddltrvehicle` -

Try this:

```
$('#ddltrVehicle').html($('#ddlvehicle').html().trim());
```

[In jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nwZq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        $(function(){
            $('#ddltrvehicle').html('');
            var option = '';
            $('#ddlvehicle option').each(function(){
                option  += '<option value="'+this.value+'">'+this.value+'</option>';
            })
            $('#ddltrvehicle').html(option);
        })
```